# Having an issue accessing a returned string array in a switch

Tags: c#

Currently working on a school project and I can't seem to wrap my head around what's going on here. What i'm trying to do is create a library system that can add items remove items ect, Currently working on the Additem Method and i've put the 3 variables required into a string and returned the string to a switch for the main menu I want it to keep the information in memory. but when it's returned to the switch when I try and writeline to verify that the information made the transfer I just get "system.string[]" printed instead of the 3 variables of the string.. Heres the two portions of code First the array

```
    public Array AddItem()
        {
            string Input = "";
            while (true)
            {
                //Media type selection screen
                Console.WriteLine("Please select the Item type");
                Console.WriteLine("1. Book");
                Console.WriteLine("2. DVD");
                Console.WriteLine("3. CD");
                Console.WriteLine("4. Magazines");
                Console.WriteLine("0. Back");
                Console.Write(":>");
                Input = Console.ReadLine();
                if (Input == "1" && Input.Length < 2)
                {
                    //Book information requests
                    string[] Bookinfo = new string[3];
                    Console.Write("What is the title of the Item: ");
                    Bookinfo[0] = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("What is the Value of the Item: ");
                    Bookinfo[1] = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("What is the ISBN Of the Item: ");
                    Bookinfo[2] = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine($"Item {Bookinfo[0]} with the value {Bookinfo[1]} has been added to the system");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(700);
                    return Bookinfo;
                }
```

and now the switch

```
                        case 2:
                            {
                                if (Input == "1")
                                {
                                 Array ItemInfo = Library.AddItem();
                                    Console.WriteLine($"{ItemInfo}");
                                    Console.ReadKey();
                                }
                                break;
                            }
```

in advance help is much appreciated.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine()` doesn't automatically show the contents of an array, you have to make it do that yourself (as in give it a string that contains all the information you want it to show). Also if you just want to verify the contents, I would look at some guides to debugging. It's possibly yo few the contents of the array inside visual studio while running the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this line: `Console.WriteLine($"{ItemInfo}");`

`ItemInfo` is an `Array`, which doesn't implement the `ToString` method so `Console.WriteLine` will print its type.

To print the 3 variables you can use `String.Join` like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", (string[])ItemInfo));
```

Also, you don't have to use `Array` according to what you sent, you can just use `string[]`.

Unrelated, when you print only one object, you can use `Console.WriteLine(Item);` instead of `Console.WriteLine($"{Item}");`, the string is unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you, I'm using array because I needed to return an array no?

Comment: Is it a homework problem and you were **explicitly** requested to return `Array`? Because if you only work with arrays of strings `string[]` will work fine.